# My gcloud server getting stopped after 1 hour after installing cpanel on it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, centos7, gcloud

My gcloud server is unable to connect after i have installed cpanel on it, and unable to connect to it.
Server configurations,
centos 7
n1 with 3.7 gb ram

Comment: Are you seeing something in the instance logs? Have you tried using the [serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)? What error are you getting when connecting with ssh?

Comment: I am getting this site can't be reached after 1-2 hours of installing cpanel

Comment: But you can still ssh to it? maybe apache is down?

Comment: also I am not able to access ssh in gcloud after that happens

Comment: Sorry but the question is too broad, there are no details on what has been tried to troubleshoot, also I have mentioned some things you can try like connecting with serial port without feedback, please review the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a good question.

As a general advise please review this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) that has several things you can try to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Installing cpanel, reboot of VM is necessary for cpanel to work smoothly.

Try **rebooting the VM instance** from the VM instances page in gcloud